# Conexiones a Base de datos Oracle con Python

Tags: python, oracle

He intentado hacer desde mi script una conexión a una BBDD de Oracle mediante

```
import cx_Oracle
```

Desde mi máquina local funciona bien (Tengo un Oracle de 32 y 64 bits) pero en el cliente tengo un error debido a que tienen instalado un Oracle de 32 y un python de 64. (Los cuales no puedo tocar ni cambiar de versiones).

He probado ha hacer la conexion con JayDeBeapi pero me pide dependencias (Jpype,...)

¿Conocéis alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Añade el error que te sale.

Comment: JayDeBeapi: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14. is required -->En la maquina del cliente no puedo instalarlo.

Comment: Para  :
JayDeBeapi: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14. is required -->En la maquina del cliente no puedo instalarlo.

Para cx_Oracle: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded. -->El cliente usa Oracle 32 bits, y tiene instalado python 64 bits que genera conflicto.

Comment: Instala el cliente de 64 bits de Oracle en la máquina del cliente. No tienes que cambiar ni el servidor, que SI puede ser de 32 bits, ni el python, que si puede ser de 64 bits. Lo que si debes hacer es cumplir las dependencias. Si no puedes hacer eso, quizás lo que va quedando es informarle al cliente que no es posible realizar la conexión. Un saludo.